# Nested For loop exited after 22 items in 27 items, running on Node server side

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops

[Modified]
A little help here can do.
I ran into a problem with for loop. I got one for loop nested in another. The outer loop has just level of elements, while the nested contains only 27 items.
The problem is that the setup can only run through 22 items of the nested array before exiting.

The setup is running on the server side, done in node.js. The Client is React which communicates with the server through websocket. From the console report, node.js runs the above code 3x; and in all those times, only 22 items are looped out of the expected 27.

Join at Repl for the full Node.js dir:
https://replit.com/join/uabhesdiif-emexrevolarter

The code below. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

VerifyResult.js

```
    let data = {};
    let error = [];
    let feedback = [];

    if(typeof dataJson == 'string') {
        data = JSON.parse(dataJson)
    } else {
        data = dataJson;
    }

    try {
        // get variables
        const getAvatarState = data.settings.isAvatar;
        const getIdState = data.settings.isAdminId;
        const getStudents = data.students[0]['Students Data'];
        const getClassInfo = data.students[0]['Class Info'][0];
        const getAvatars = data.images;
        const getLogo = data.logo;
        const getFilenames = data.filenames;
        const getFirstTermState = data.settings.isFirstTerm;
        const getSecondTermState = data.settings.isSecondTerm;
        const getThirdTermState = data.settings.isThirdTerm;
        const getSubjectList = data.subjects;
        let getFirstTerm = [];
        let getSecondTerm  =[];
        let getThirdTerm = [];

        // verify #1: if avatars are permitted & same number of images included
        if(getAvatarState == '1') {
            if(getStudents.length > getAvatars.length) {
                feedback.push(`${getAvatars.length} Images supplied for Avatar is lesser than the number of ${getStudents.length} students`);
                feedback.push('Some Results may not include Avatar')
            }
            if(getStudents.length < getAvatars.length) {
                feedback.push(`${getAvatars.length} Images supplied for Avatar is more than the number of ${getStudents.length} students`);
                feedback.push('This may not pose any problem except possible mismatch')
            }
        } else {
            feedback.push('Avatar will not be included in any result')
        }

        // verify #2: if logo is included
        if(getLogo == null) {
            feedback.push('No image was added as logo, and hence, will not be included')
        }

        // verify #3: if empty value for Admin Numbers, Names, in Students file
        let idList = [];
        let countItem = 0;
        let innerCount = 0;
        for(let k = 0; k < getStudents.length; k++) {
            let d = getStudents[k];
            countItem = k + 1;
            let fName, lName;

            if(getIdState == '1') {
                if(d.Admin_Number != undefined && d.Admin_Number != '') {
                    idList.push(d.Admin_Number);
                } else {
                    error.push(`Admin Number for Student at row "${countItem}" is empty, in Students workbook`)
                }
            }

            if(d.Firstname != undefined && d.Firstname != '') {
                fName = d.Firstname
            } else {
                error.push(`Firstname for Student at row "${countItem}" is empty, in Students workbook`)
            }
            if(d.Surname != undefined && d.Surname != '') {
                lName = d.Surname
            } else {
                error.push(`Surname for Student at row "${countItem}" is empty, in Students workbook`)
            }
            if(fName != undefined && lName != undefined) {
                (getIdState == '0') && idList.push(`${lName}/${fName}`);
            }
        };

        // verify #4: if IDs for Students file is unique
        if(!IsArrayUnique(idList)) {
            (getIdState == '1') && error.push(`One or Student Admin Numbers are not unique, in Students file`);
            (getIdState == '0') && error.push(`One or more Student names are not unique, in Students file`);
        }

        // verify #5: if empty value for Class Info, in Students file
        if(getClassInfo.Class_Name == undefined) {
            error.push('Class Name of Class Info worksheet is empty, in Students file')
        }
        if(getClassInfo.School == undefined) {
            error.push('School Name of Class Info worksheet is empty, in Students file')
        }
        if(getClassInfo.Session == undefined) {
            error.push('Session of Class Info worksheet is empty, in Students file')
        }
        if(getClassInfo.Times_School_Opened == undefined) {
            error.push('No of Times School Opened of Class Info worksheet is empty, in Students file')
        }

        countItem = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < getSubjectList.length; i++) {
            let sub = getSubjectList[i];
            let gFile = getFilenames[i];
            countItem = i + 1;
            let innError = false;
            let list = [];
            let subj, fName, lName, sName, termName;

            if(getFirstTermState == '1') {
                // verify #6: if empty value in Subject files for First Term
                innError = false;
                termName = 'First Term';
                subj = sub['First Term'];
                if(sub['Class Info'][0].Class_Name == undefined) {
                    innError = true;
                    error.push(`Class Name in ${gFile} is empty`)
                }
                if(sub['Class Info'][0].Subject == undefined) {
                    innError = true;
                    error.push(`Subject Name in ${gFile} is empty`)
                }
                if(subj < 1) {
                    innError = true;
                    error.push(`Subject scores for ${termName} cannot be found in ${gFile}`)
                }

                if(!innError) {
                    console.log('==== STUDENTS TOTAL: ', subj.length);
                    innerCount = 0;
                    for(let j = 0; j < subj.length; j++) {
                        let item = subj[j];
                        innerCount = j + 1;
                        if(item.Surname == undefined) {
                            innError = true;
                            error.push(`Surname for a Student at row ${innerCount} is empty, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                        }
                        if(item.Firstname == undefined) {
                            innError = true;
                            error.push(`Firstname for a Student at row ${innerCount} is empty, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                        }
                        if(item.Admin_Number == undefined && getIdState == '1') {
                            innError = true;
                            error.push(`Admin Number for a Student at row ${innerCount} is empty, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                        }

                        if(!innError) {
                            fName = item.Firstname;
                            lName = item.Surname;
                            if(item.CA == undefined && !innError) {
                                innError = true;
                                error.push(`CA for "${lName} ${fName}" at row ${innerCount} is empty, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                            }
                            if(item.Exam == undefined && !innError) {
                                innError = true;
                                error.push(`Exam for "${lName} ${fName}" at row ${innerCount} is empty, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                            }
                        }

                        // verify #7: if both CA & Exam are numbers for First Term
                        if(!innError) {
                            console.log('====== TOTAL READ: ', innerCount + ' | ' + countItem);
                            console.log('====== IS CA A NUMBER?: ', item.CA + ' | ' + IsNumber(item.CA));
                            console.log('====== IS Exam A NUMBER?: ', item.Exam + ' | ' + IsNumber(item.Exam));
                            if(!IsNumber(item.CA)) {
                                innError = true;
                                error.push(`CA for "${lName} ${fName}" at row ${innerCount} is not a number (${item.CA}), for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                            }
                            if(!IsNumber(item.Exam)) {
                                innError = true;
                                error.push(`Exam for "${lName} ${fName}" at row ${innerCount} is not a number (${item.Exam}), for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                            }
                        }

                        // verify #8: if Total is > 45 & < 50
                        if(!innError) {
                            const itemTotal = Number(item.CA) + Number(item.Exam);
                            if(itemTotal > 45 && itemTotal < 50) {
                                innError = true;
                                error.push(`The CA (CA: ${item.CA}; Exam: ${item.Exam}; Total: ${itemTotal}) for "${lName} ${fName}" at row ${innerCount}, should be upgraded to 50, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                            }
                        }

                        if(!innError) {
                            if(getIdState == '1'){
                                sName = item.Admin_Number;
                                list.push(sName);
                            } else {
                                sName = lName + '/' + fName;
                                list.push(`${sName}`);
                            }

                            // verify #9: match IDs as Admin Number or Names for First Term
                            if(idList.indexOf(sName) === -1) {
                                innError = true;
                                (getIdState == '1') && error.push(`Student Admin Number "${sName}" is mismatched, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`);
                                (getIdState == '0') && error.push(`Student name "${lName} ${fName}" is mismatched, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // verify #10: if unique IDs for First Term
                    if(!innError) {
                        if(idList.length == list.length) {
                            if(!IsArrayUnique(list)){
                                innError = true;
                                (getIdState == '1') && error.push(`One or more Student Admin Numbers are not unique, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                                (getIdState == '0') && error.push(`One or more Student names are not unique, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`);
                            }
                        } else {
                            innError = true;
                            error.push(`Found ${list.length} Students against expected ${idList.length} number of Students, for ${termName} in ${gFile}`)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        
        // verify #3: match admin Id is set as active, else match students names

    } catch (err) {
        error.push(err)
    }

    const res = {
        data: data,
        error: error,
        feedback: feedback
    }
```

data.json

```
{"settings":{"isAdminId":"1","isFirstTerm":"1","isSecondTerm":"0","isThirdTerm":"0","isAvatar":"1","isVerify":"1"},"subjects":[{"First Term":[{"Surname":"ADEOLA","Firstname":"TOLUWALASE","CA":38,"Exam":56,"Admin_Number":"AND/J/0271"},{"Surname":"ADEMOLA","Firstname":"SAMUEL","CA":35,"Exam":55,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0273"},{"Surname":"AGBONIRO","Firstname":"JESSE","CA":40,"Exam":54,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0284"},{"Surname":"AJAYI","Firstname":"ABIGAIL","CA":23,"Exam":33,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0269"},{"Surname":"AKANDE","Firstname":"MICHAEL","CA":29,"Exam":41,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0267"},{"Surname":"AKINTOKUN","Firstname":"MOFE","CA":27,"Exam":47,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0272"},{"Surname":"ARTHUR","Firstname":"DESTINY","CA":33,"Exam":55,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0266"},{"Surname":"AYANWENU","Firstname":"AKOREDE","CA":22,"Exam":35,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0270"},{"Surname":"BETHEL","Firstname":"MOYINULUWA","CA":40,"Exam":58,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0274"},{"Surname":"CHIJIOKE","Firstname":"JOY","CA":26,"Exam":44,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0276"},{"Surname":"CHINWUBA","Firstname":"CHARLES","CA":33,"Exam":40,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0275"},{"Surname":"DAVID","Firstname":"BEST","CA":40,"Exam":59,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0277"},{"Surname":"DUYILE","Firstname":"IFEOLUWA","CA":29,"Exam":41,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0256"},{"Surname":"EZEADILI","Firstname":"CHIBUNDU","CA":35,"Exam":49,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0278"},{"Surname":"FAGITE","Firstname":"TOBILOBA","CA":40,"Exam":57,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0279"},{"Surname":"IDOGEN","Firstname":"EHIZOFUA","CA":31,"Exam":51,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0282"},{"Surname":"IFADA","Firstname":"HOSSONA","CA":33,"Exam":50,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0255"},{"Surname":"IHEDIOHA","Firstname":"DELIGHT","CA":34,"Exam":53,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0280"},{"Surname":"JOSIAH","Firstname":"MATTHEW","CA":29,"Exam":49,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0283"},{"Surname":"MBONU","Firstname":"MMESOMA","CA":32,"Exam":45,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0285"},{"Surname":"NWONU","Firstname":"DAVID","CA":27,"Exam":41,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0260"},{"Surname":"OBI","Firstname":"LUCIA","CA":20,"Exam":26,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0289"},{"Surname":"ODOZOR","Firstname":"AUSTIN","CA":19,"Exam":29,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0249"},{"Surname":"OLAWALE","Firstname":"MOYINOLUWA","CA":29,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0290"},{"Surname":"OKERENITE","Firstname":"SPLENDID","Exam":53,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0287"},{"Surname":"OKUSHI","Firstname":"DANIEL","CA":32,"Exam":"x","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0288"},{"Surname":"DABRINZE","Firstname":"POSSIBLE","CA":"y","Exam":40,"Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0250"}],"Second Term":[],"Third Term":[],"Class Info":[{"Class_Name":"JS2 Goodness","Subject":"BST (Information Tech.)"}],"ID":[{"Id":"Subjects","Start_Row":3}]}],"filenames":["subject_ict.xlsx"],"students":[{"Students Data":[{"Surname":"ADEOLA","Firstname":"TOLUWALASE","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"AND/J/0271","DOB":"26 FEB 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126,"Override_Teacher_Comment":"very naughty","Override_Skills_Musical":3,"Override_Skills_Painting":4,"Override_Skills_Craft":3,"Override_Skills_Tools":3,"Override_Skills_Fluency":4,"Override_Sports_Indoor":4,"Override_Sports_Ball":4,"Override_Sports_Combative":3,"Override_Sports_Track":3,"Override_Sports_Gymnastics":4,"Override_Curricular_Jets":5,"Override_Curricular_Farmers":3,"Override_Curricular_Debating":4,"Override_Curricular_Homemaker":5,"Override_Curricular_Drama":5,"Override_Curricular_Voluntary":4,"Override_Curricular_Others":3,"Override_Behaviour_Reliability":5,"Override_Behaviour_Neatness":5,"Override_Behaviour_Politeness":5,"Override_Behaviour_Honesty":5,"Override_Behaviour_Creativity":4,"Override_Behaviour_Leadership":5,"Override_Behaviour_Spirituality":5,"Override_Behaviour_Cooporation":5},{"Surname":"ADEMOLA","Firstname":"SAMUEL","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0273","DOB":"27 MAY 2009","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"AGBONIRO","Firstname":"JESSE","House":"Red","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0284","DOB":"9 SEPT 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"AJAYI","Firstname":"ABIGAIL","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0269","DOB":"JUNE 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":120},{"Surname":"AKANDE","Firstname":"MICHAEL","House":"Red","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0267","DOB":"29 DEC 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"AKINTOKUN","Firstname":"MOFE","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0272","DOB":"21 JULY 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"ARTHUR","Firstname":"DESTINY","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0266","DOB":"23 AUG 2009","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"AYANWENU","Firstname":"AKOREDE","House":"Blue","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0270","DOB":"17 MAY 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"BETHEL","Firstname":"MOYINULUWA","House":"Blue","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0274","DOB":"13 MAR 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"CHIJIOKE","Firstname":"JOY","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0276","DOB":"27 FEB 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"CHINWUBA","Firstname":"CHARLES","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0275","DOB":"15 MAY 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":122},{"Surname":"DAVID","Firstname":"BEST","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0277","DOB":"3 MAR 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"DUYILE","Firstname":"IFEOLUWA","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0256","DOB":"8 JAN 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"EZEADILI","Firstname":"CHIBUNDU","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0278","DOB":"14 FEB 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"FAGITE","Firstname":"TOBILOBA","House":"Blue","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0279","DOB":"26 AUG 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"IDOGEN","Firstname":"EHIZOFUA","House":"Blue","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0282","DOB":"6 JUNE 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"IFADA","Firstname":"HOSSONA","House":"Red","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0255","DOB":"12 OCT 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"IHEDIOHA","Firstname":"DELIGHT","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0280","DOB":"4 NOV 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"JOSIAH","Firstname":"MATTHEW","House":"Red","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0283","DOB":"13 AUG 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"MBONU","Firstname":"MMESOMA","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0285","DOB":"17 MAY 2009","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"NWONU","Firstname":"DAVID","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0260","DOB":"29 AUG 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":124},{"Surname":"OBI","Firstname":"LUCIA","House":"Red","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0289","DOB":"29 DEC 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"ODOZOR","Firstname":"AUSTIN","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0249","DOB":"9 AUG 2008","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"OLAWALE","Firstname":"MOYINOLUWA","House":"Red","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0290","DOB":"19 SEP 2010","Sex":"F","Times_Present":108},{"Surname":"OKERENITE","Firstname":"SPLENDID","House":"Green","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0287","DOB":"14 DEC 2009","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"OKUSHI","Firstname":"DANIEL","House":"Blue","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0288","DOB":"29 SEP 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126},{"Surname":"DABRINZE","Firstname":"POSSIBLE","House":"Yellow","Admin_Number":"ADM/J/0250","DOB":"20 JUN 2010","Sex":"M","Times_Present":126}],"Class Info":[{"Class_Name":"JS2 Goodness","School":"Junior Secondary","Session":"2021/2022","Times_School_Opened":126,"Next_Term_Begins":"4th January, 2022"}],"Settings":[{"Id_By_Admin_No":"Yes","First_Term_Active":"Yes","Second_Term_Active":"No","Third_Term_Active":"No","Students_Photos":"Yes","Verify":"Yes"}],"ID":[{"Id":"Students","Start_Row":3}]}],"keys":[{"Junior Grade Keys":[{"Grade_Name":"A","Min_Value":70,"Max_Value":100},{"Grade_Name":"B","Min_Value":60,"Max_Value":69.9},{"Grade_Name":"C","Min_Value":50,"Max_Value":59.9},{"Grade_Name":"P","Min_Value":40,"Max_Value":49.9},{"Grade_Name":"F","Min_Value":0,"Max_Value":39.9}],"Senior Grade Keys":[{"Grade_Name":"A","Min_Value":75,"Max_Value":100},{"Grade_Name":"B2","Min_Value":70,"Max_Value":74.9},{"Grade_Name":"B3","Min_Value":65,"Max_Value":69.9},{"Grade_Name":"C4","Min_Value":60,"Max_Value":64.9},{"Grade_Name":"C5","Min_Value":55,"Max_Value":59.9},{"Grade_Name":"C6","Min_Value":50,"Max_Value":54.9},{"Grade_Name":"D7","Min_Value":45,"Max_Value":49.9},{"Grade_Name":"E8","Min_Value":40,"Max_Value":44.9},{"Grade_Name":"F9","Min_Value":0,"Max_Value":39.9}],"Rating Keys":[{"Rating_Name":"Skill","Min_Value":2,"Max_Value":5},{"Rating_Name":"Sports","Min_Value":2,"Max_Value":5},{"Rating_Name":"Curricular","Min_Value":2,"Max_Value":5},{"Rating_Name":"Behaviour","Min_Value":2,"Max_Value":5}],"School Info":[{"School_Name":"SAMUEL ADEGBITE ANGLICAN COLLEGE","Extra_Info":"(A Day-Co-educational Institution Of The Anglican Diocese Of Lagos West)","Address":"St. Peters Anglican Church, Ikotun Road, Idumu, Lagos.","Title":"SECONDARY SCHOOL STUDENT'S INTERNAL ACADEMIC REPORT SHEET","Watermark":"SAMUEL ADEGBITE ANGLICAN COLLEGE"},{"Address":null,"Title":null},{"Address":null,"Title":null},{"Address":null,"Title":null}],"ID":[{"Id":"DON'T CHANGE!!!","Start_Row":null},{"Id":"File ID","Start_Row":"Start Row"},{"Id":"Keys","Start_Row":1},{"Id":null}]}],"pool":[{"Principal Comment":[{"Pool":"Good  performance,  keep  it  up"},{"Pool":"A  wonderful  performance,  keep  it  up"},{"Pool":"A  highly  impressive  result,  keep  it  up"},{"Pool":"Good  result  but  you  need  to  improve  in  your  weak  area(s)"},{"Pool":"Average  result,  there  is  still  room  for  improvement"},{"Pool":"Average  result,  you  can  still  do  better"},{"Pool":"A  fair  result,  you  really  need  to  improve  in  your  weak  subject(s)"},{"Pool":"Weak  performance,  you  really  need  to  improve  in  your  weak  subjects"},{"Pool":"A  very  good  performance,  keep  it  up"},{"Pool":"Beautiful  performance,  keep  the  flag  flying"},{"Pool":"Weak  result,  you  need  to  concentrate  more  on  your studies"},{"Pool":"Excellent  performance,  keep  it  up"},{"Pool":"A  brilliant  performance,  keep  it  up"},{"Pool":"Good result, there is room for improvement"},{"Pool":"An average result, you really need to study harder"},{"Pool":"A very good result, weldone."},{"Pool":"A  beautiful  result, keep it up"},{"Pool":"An  impressive  result, keep it up"},{"Pool":"A  very  good  performance, keep the flag flying"},{"Pool":"An average result, there is still room for improvement,"},{"Pool":"A  fair result, you can still do better."},{"Pool":"A weak result, there is room for you to work harder."},{"Pool":"A very weak performance, you seriously need to work harder."},{"Pool":"Poor performance, your need to work on your weak subjects"},{"Pool":"Excellent performance, keep it up."},{"Pool":null}],"Teacher Comment":[{"Pool":"Always   willing   to  take  up   responsiblities"},{"Pool":"Very  friendly  and  humorous"},{"Pool":"A  highly  talented   student"},{"Pool":"Very  hardworking  and  conscioustious"},{"Pool":"Friendly  but  needs  to  put  in  more  efforts"},{"Pool":"Easy-going   and   very   neat"},{"Pool":"Always  punctual   to  class  and  all  other  activities"},{"Pool":"Highly  dependable  and  trustworthy"},{"Pool":"Very  reliable   and   hardworking"},{"Pool":"Active  and  always  willing  to  take  up  responsibilities"},{"Pool":"Friendly  but  needs  to  pay  more  attention  to  his/her  studies"},{"Pool":"Friendly  but  needs  to  settle  down  for  serious  work"},{"Pool":"Easy-going  but  needs  to  be  more  punctual"},{"Pool":"Very  studious  and  always  attentive  in  class"},{"Pool":"Very  reliable  and  willing  to assist  others"},{"Pool":"Highly  cooperative  and  dependable"},{"Pool":"Friendly  but  needs  to  be  less  playful"},{"Pool":"Friendly  but  restless, needs to always observe siesta"},{"Pool":"Highly  organized  and  conscientious"},{"Pool":"Friendly  and  highly  willing  to  learn"},{"Pool":"A  consistent  and  handworking  student"},{"Pool":"Very  reliable  and  ready  to  take  to correction"},{"Pool":null},{"Pool":null},{"Pool":null}],"Skills":[{"Pool":"Musical Instrument"},{"Pool":"Drawing and Painting"},{"Pool":"Craft"},{"Pool":"Handling of Workshop Tools"},{"Pool":"Handwriting/Fluency"}],"Sports":[{"Pool":"Indoor Games"},{"Pool":"Ball Games"},{"Pool":"Combative Games"},{"Pool":"Track/Throws"},{"Pool":"Gymnastics"}],"Curricular":[{"Pool":"JETS"},{"Pool":"Young Farmers Club"},{"Pool":"Literary & Debating"},{"Pool":"Home Maker"},{"Pool":"Drama/Culture/Music/Craft"},{"Pool":"Voluntary Service Org."},{"Pool":"Others"}],"Behaviour":[{"Pool":"Reliability"},{"Pool":"Neatness"},{"Pool":"Politeness"},{"Pool":"Honesty"},{"Pool":"Initiative/Creativity"},{"Pool":"Leadership Role"},{"Pool":"Level of Spiritual Dev.","Override":3},{"Pool":"Spirit of Co-operation"}],"ID":[{"Id":"DON'T CHANGE!!!","Start_Row":null},{"Id":"File ID","Start_Row":"Start Row"},{"Id":"Pool","Start_Row":1}]}],"logo":null,"images":["stunt toy car.jpg"],"errors":[]}
```

Comment: The code is fine as it is. Without any example data, it's impossible to say what's going wrong.  One possibility is that some `subj[j]` is `null` or `undefined`, thus `item.Surname` will throw an error. Another possibility is, that `error` is not what you think it is (it's not defined anywhere in the visible code). So it might as well be `null` or `undefined` and thus `error.push` might also throw an exception

Comment: Please provide runnable snippet, including the data. And what's exactly expected/received instead of "only run through 22 items". How do you know it's 22?

Comment: I console.log j, and it always gave 22. I tested the setup with other looping types, such as forEach, and map functions. As per the variables, they are all defined, but not shown in the code above. Actually, the whole code is contained in try/catch, hence, no error thrown.

I forgot to mention that the setup is running on the server side, done in node.js. The Client is React which communicates with the server through websocket.

Comment: I have not experienced this premature exiting of loop before. From the console report, node.js runs the above code 3x; and in all those times, only 22 items are looped out of the expected 27.

As for providing he whole snippet, it is kinda too long. Like I said, no error is being caught by the try/catch.

Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the Question to show the whole snippet.
I appreciate the help so far.

I hope to get a solution to this node.js behavior, soon.

Comment: So it's the `for(let j = 0; j < subj.length; j++)` loop you are talking about, right? Assuming the above is the exact code you use, (and there are no exceptions, like you say) there is no way, the loop exits before `j == subj.length` So if you expect 27 iterations but only get 22, you should check your data, if it meets your expectations, ie check if `subj.length == 27` And again: Nobody is able to verify your problems if you don't add any example data. And nobody will join any third party site to view your code or example ...

Comment: I  purposely added this line:
console.log('==== STUDENTS TOTAL: ', subj.length);
It gave 27, showing the exact data expected.

I edited the question again to add the sample data json.

Comment: I tried your code with your data and it is -- as expected -- iterating over all 27 items. But because some condition isn't met, you are setting `innerr = true` for the 22nd record and never setting it back to `false`. So all items after that will be treated like they have an error too (which probalby makes you believe they are not iterated). Just try adding a `console.log(j)` as first statement in your inner loop. And you will see, it will printout all values from `0` to `26` ...

Comment: @derpirscher I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: I just tested it now, and surprisingly printed the rest of data: 23 - 27.
I had thought something fishy was happening with for loop. Phew!

Comment: Found it!
The condition if(itemTotal > 45 && itemTotal < 50) is not passed for item 23, hence sets innError to true. This is desirable though, but I totally forgot that such condition can limit the result retrieved by console.log if placed later in the loop.

Thanks men, especially @derpirscher. I appreciate so very much.

Please, how do I mark this as answered?

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. You can upvote and/or accept it ...

Comment: I see it already. No wonder, a solution must be added as an answer before the upvote and accept buttons will be displayed. You earned it @derpirscher.
Thank you so much once again. Happy Christmas and more blessings.

Comment: Please @derpirscher, why is it that @ mentions doesn't add link to the referred User here on Stackoverflow? Like on app.slack.com, it works, just like it does on other social media too such as Facebook & Instagram, with auto-complete.

Comment: They are not converted to a link, but the respective user (in this case me) get notified about the mention nonetheless ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with your data and it is -- as expected -- iterating over all 27 items. But because some condition isn't met, you are setting `innError = true` for the 22nd record and never setting it back to `false`.

So all items after that will be treated like they have an error too (which probably makes you believe they are not iterated). Just try adding a `console.log(j)` as first statement in your inner loop. And you will see, it will printout all values from `0` to `26` ...